# Android: TextView, unicode character not shown properly

Tags: java, android, unicode, textview

I add a rating to a `TextView` programmatically by setting some unicode stars. It's the unicode star [\u22C6](http://unicode-table.com/en/#22C6), but the `TextView` shows me this character when I start the app: [\u22A0](http://unicode-table.com/en/#22A0).

This is how I created it:

```
private CharSequence calculatedSelectedRating(Integer rating)
{
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

    //Star is &#8902; or \u22C6
    for (int i = 0; i < rating; i++)
    {
        stringBuffer.append('\u22C6');
    }

    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

and the result is what I set in `TextView` by `setText(...)` method.

Any ideas why this discrepancy occurs?

Comment: ' is for char , " is for String ;)

Comment: @MuhammadFarrukhFaizy `'` is correct since I add a single character, unicode encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some fonts don't support some characters. Check your message is shown with other font; include the ttf file on your assets folder, and set the content of the TextView with that font with something like:

```
yourTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.idOfYourTextView);
Typeface font= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "The_Font.TTF");
yourTextView.setTypeface(font);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You are right. Obviously Android does not support all Unicode characters, argh. Then I need to use a different one or a graphic. But the strange this is, it works in another view. Maybe there is still some other problem, but basically it has to do with the font.

Comment: UPDATE: There is no other problem. On the other view, I used the default asterisk which is supported by Android. So it's really a problem with a missing character in Android's default font.

Comment: Great. I was thinking on what it could be.

Answer (score 1):

try using `"` instead of `'`

```
stringBuffer.append("\u22C6");
```

Comment: This does not work, same result. We are talking about a unicode character, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

On your TextView, you can use HTML format to set the text. Do something like this

```
mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Comment: That's a good workaround, but unfortunately I have the same erroneous results. (I passed the character as html notation `&#8902;` and changed the return type into String)